# Kendo Grid Datasource Update 0:N child table rows

Tags: odata, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

I have a requirement to update multiple tables using a Kendo grid. The grid is using a Kendo datasource to read and update remote data via service calls(OData/Entity Framework).

- Currently the grid can read/write data from say Table_A.
- Table_A can has a one to many relation with Table_B. I'm able to retrieve the Table_B items during read using $expand: {'Table_B'}
- On edit row item, I need to update the N items in Table_B as well. I tried updating the child items available in the model(data.Table_B.results) but I get a 413 error saying Request Entity Too Large.

So when editing a grid item, is it possible to:

1. Update the parent and child rows in a single update?
2. Or is it possible update the parent row first and then update the child rows

I have searched for examples but can't find any so far. Any ideas or examples?

Answer (score 1):

The 2 options are both ok.

For the first one, the Batch feature is needed, that is, wrapping several requests in to one multi-part http request.

For the second, it is quite straightforward, and several requests need to be sent, for example:

1. PUT/PATCH ~/odata/Orders(1)
2. PUT/PATCH ~/odata/Orders(1)/OrderLines(1)
3. PUT/PATCH ~/odata/Orders(1)/OrderLines(2)

If you just start to use OData, I recommend to start from OData v4, as from this version it became a standard of OASIS several weeks ago. Here are some samples for your reference: https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/